# Bitcoins unconfirmed even after double spend

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum, doublespend, replace-by-fee

I'm very new to bitcoin and recently bought 0.066 bitcoins and transferred them to my electrum wallet. I then transferred them to another wallet but I set the fee too low (40Sat/b) and it was stuck in blockchain for a few days before returning to my wallet. From there I resent the coins with a much higher fee (100Sat/b) and it said that I double spent the fees. After waiting for an hour this transaction also hadn't been confirmed so I used the increase fee tool in electrum and increased the fees yet again (260Sat/b). After waiting another 45-60 minutes it still hadn't confirmed. So, dumb me decided to increase the fees again and it all seemed to work except this time when I went to view the transaction on blockchain I was greeted with this...

"Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction double spends an input too many times DBOutput{outPoint=OutpointImpl{txIndex=223924437, txOutputN=5}, spending_outpoints=[OutpointImpl{txIndex=223932999, txOutputN=0}, OutpointImpl{txIndex=224715242, txOutputN=0}, OutpointImpl{txIndex=22473446"

This concerned me as on electrum it shows that the transaction is in the block and awaiting confirmation, yet it isn't according to blockchain. The previous attempts of raising the fees are still listed as awaiting confirmation on blockchain here: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/224734462
Any help would be greatly appreciated, my main concern is getting the bitcoins back and being able to transfer them to this wallet in a timely fashion, but if someone could just explain what is happening I would be very thankful!

Comment: your transaction is accepted with block.

Comment: Note that a transaction is either **"in the block" OR "awaiting confirmation"**. A transaction gets its first confirmation by being included in a block.